# How to find all documents from partial index in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Suppose I have a database `users` with a partial index:

```
db.users.createIndex(
   { username: 1 },
   { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { age: { $gte: 21 } } }
)
```

I want to find all documents for query:

```
db.users.find(
       {age: { $gte: 21 }}
)
```

However, this query will not use my index despite the fact that all I need is to find all documents from the index.

What should I do to use this index for my purpose?

Comment: No, because there is no index on `age`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
db.users.find({ username:{ $ne:null }, age:{ $gte: 21 }})
```

If you have null users, try:

```
db.users.find({$or:[{username:{ $ne:null}},{username: {$eq:null }}], age:{ $gte: 21 }})
```

**Considerations**

- MongoDB requires the indexed field to be in the query, to use an index
- There may be other suitable conditions (`$exists` won't work), but I find this useful enough.
- Add `.explain()` to see the parsed Query and the usage of Indexes.
- Tested

Comment: But what if I want to get all documents from the index, not only those in which username not null. Could I do that?

Comment: Try the new one, I just thought username would be required, so it can't be null. @GiorgiyPopov add `.explain()` if you want to see the parsedQuery

Answer (score 1):

I guess this one should also work (but I did not test):

```
db.users.find({}).min({}).hint({ username: 1 })
```